# Solving equations involving exponential and linear growth

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

How do I resolve this type of equations without input different $x$ values to find the $y$ values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us tanslate the data $$F=20000\times (1.05)^{y}$$ $$C=25000+y\times500$$ You can graph the two functions and notice when $C>F$.

Otherwise, you need a numerical method to first solve the equation $$f(y)=20000\times (1.05)^{y}-(25000+500y)$$ and Newton method is probably the simplest. Being lazy, let us start with $y_0=0$. The successive iterates will then be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & y_n \\
  0 & 0 \\
 1 & 10.5 \\
 2 & 7.73 \\
 3 & 7.41 \\
 4 & 7.40
\end{array}
\right)$$

Let us check : after $7$ years, $F=28142$ and $C=28500$;  after $8$ years, $F=29549$ and $C=29000$.

Comment: I think your $y_n$ corresponds to what OP called "$x$ values" in the question.

Comment: @DavidK. You are correct !

Answer (score 2):

"How do I resolve this type of equations without input different $x$ values to find the $y$ values?"

The answer is: you don't.

Instead, you *do* input different $x$ values to find $y$ values and thereby find the solution.
Newton's method (mentioned in another answer) is a methodical way to choose the $x$ values that you will input. There are also other ways to choose the input values.